# In a Jenkinsfile, anyway to make the shared library version programmable?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I usually do this when using a shared library, in my `Jenkinsfile.`

```
@Library("my-shared-lib@2.0.0") _
...
```

But every time I update my shared library, I update the version accordingly using semantic versioning. For example, for bug fixes I update to version `2.0.1`, and for breaking changes, I update to version `3.0.0`.

So for the modules that use my shared library, I need to create a Bitbucket pull request to update the version accordingly in the line above in their respective `Jenkinsfile`s. Is there a good way to circumvent this, by using a variable maybe to set the version? Thanks

Comment: I do not believe it can be defined with a variable or parameter as it is declarative. However, I do believe anything that is a git ref can be used so that allows for more flexibility and options here.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard, can you please elaborate on your "However..." statement, maybe in an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes you can make your library name dynamic as per the official doc [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically). Check the example below where I'm reading the library version from an input param.

```
properties([parameters([string(name: 'VERSION', defaultValue: '2.0.0')])])
library "my-shared-lib@${params.VERSION}"
```

So you can whatever logic to determine the version you want to use.

Having said that, I think the better approach is to go for a branching and tagging strategy and then let your sub-teams decide what they like to adopt based on the risk appetite of the individual teams. For example, consider the following.

**Default Branch(e.g: main/master)**: This branch has the latest code, whether you do a breaking change or a bug fix this branch will have the latest changes. So this can be the default branch of the shared library or anyone can use it as `@Library("my-shared-lib@main")`

**Major Version Branches**: When you decide to do a major version release for example 3.0.0 you can create a branch `branch-3.x` this will have all the bug fixes you do for the 3.0.0. Who ever wants to pull in latest fixes can use this branch `@Library("my-shared-lib@branch-3.x")`.

**Specific Tags**: For the teams that do not want to pull changes automatically. You can continue with the same tagging strategy. When you do a bug fix for `3.0.0` you can release `3.0.x`, whoever wants to adopt these fixes will have to update their Jenkins file.